# Meaning of "accept [...] on [...]"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

In the book "The Twenty Years' Crisis" by E. H. Carr, written in 1939, I read

> [men] accept the judgment of history on the past.

After checking [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1006?rskey=UDEXw6&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) and Merriam-Webster [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accept) and [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accept/take%20(something)%20on%20faith), I still do not understand this "accept ... on ..." structure. The only example that seems similar is in [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1006?rskey=UDEXw6&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> 1876   E. A. Freeman Hist. Norman Conquest II. App. 530   A fact which we may surely accept on the authority of the Biographer.

Could someone please help me out and rephrase the quoted sentence? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They accept the judgment. The judgment  is on the past.

We accept the fact *on the authority* of the biographer.

In neither case is 'on' grammatically linked to 'accept'.

Comment: Thank you, I accept that as an answer. Could you still please rephrase the sentence? Does history judge the past or the other way around? Or neither?

Comment: I don't know the context, but I assume Carr means that people accept history's judgment on the past, that is, the view of past events taken by historians over the years.